Kinetic proofreading - detailed balance algebra in Hopfields paper
In Hopfields paper (https://swh.princeton.edu/~wbialek/rome/refs/hopfield_74.pdf), it is suggested that multiple steps are needed to ensure proofreading, as shown in the figure below taken from the paper. In addition, they must be irreversible. In the process of proving this Hopfield simply states that in equalibrium the following equality must hold:
The paper doesn't give the algebraic derivation for this statement. It seems simple but I have not been able to work it out.

What is your question? Do you want a derivation? Please mention that.

At equilibrium, the forward and reverse rates must be equal for each reaction, therefore, if we denote a concentration by brackets, we must have (dropping the rate subscripts)
$$k'[c][C]=k[Cc]$$
$$m'[Cc]=m[Cc^*]$$
$$l'[c][C]=l[Cc^*]$$
These equations can be solved to determine the relationship between the rate constants.

My understanding is that the totality of the rates for a certain concentration sum up to zero, for example,    k′[c][C] - k[Cc] - m′[Cc] + m[Cc∗] = 0. Why should we assume this for every reaction in itself as you have presented?
